# Switch between those pages without reloading but links are changed as I switch pages

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, routes

I want to know how to implement this, for example I have a website and there is a link to the user profile 'www.myshop.com/account/profile'. And within that page, there is a navigation to switch on other account pages like 'www.myshop.com/account/delivery'. How can I switch between those pages without reloading but links are changed as I switch pages. I'm using JavaScript and PHP as languages. I hope you can help me. Thank you!

Comment: By using JavaScript frameworks or libraries.

Comment: @webCatDev I don’t see how this helps here. Just use the [History API](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/History_API).